# using click jquery function to track my clicks on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing some code to track my own clicks activity on a web page. I did this and it works well but only for some dom elements.

```
$(document).on('click','body *',function(){
  if(!trackingStopped && !TrackingPaused && startTracking){
  var domElement = $(event.target).closest();   
  localStorage.setItem("clicked",JSON.stringify(domElement.nodeName));
  }
});
```

but it doesn't work for some dom elements, for example :
[image: when I try to get the dom element I clicked on in google website]

When I click on the text search input it detects it but when I click on the google search button it doesn't detect it. It doesn't store anything in the localStorage as if I didn't clicked on anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the chrome developer tools, we can see there is already some binding on the click event for that button, see: [Google Search Button Binded Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdhcT.png)

I will guess (I've haven't verified), that one of these called functions will stop the event propagation https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: So basically there's no way I can capture clicks on elements that stop event propagation ?

Comment: Events are propagated in bubule from the element to its parents. But their capture goes from the Window to the element, you can add a listener there: see [JavaScript Event Propagation](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php#:~:text=JavaScript%20Event%20Propagation%201%20Understanding%20the%20Event%20Propagation.,Propagation.%20...%206%20Preventing%20the%20Default%20Action.%20) for more details.

Comment: Edit: You will surely need to track which element is hovered/focused at the same time, to know what was the real target element of the event; or lookup if the information you need is available in the event (not sure about that)

Comment: Thank you so much!! that really helped me.